# php query based on relational child elements for wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, meta

I will try and explain this a simple as possible.

I have 3 post types that come into play here.

1. reports
2. events (motogp-2013, motogp-2014)
3. circuits

On my 'events' single.php to display the event information, I am trying to create a query to display related 'reports'.

And the only relation that the event content can have with a report is the circuit.

---

When I create a 'report', I have to assign an 'event' to it. But when I create a 'event' prior to a report, I have to assign a 'circuit' to it.

For example, it looks like this...

```
> 'report' - Second place for Pedrosa as black flag terminates race for Marquez (1023)
   > 'event' - Australian Grand Prix (662)
      > 'circuit' - Phillip Island (156)
```

So I am trying to query 'reports', which had 'events' at specific 'circuits'.

---

On my 'events' single.php, I do have the circuit id, but I don't know how to list the reports that which are at that circuit.

I can easily show related 'events' using this query

```
$related = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('motogp-2013','motogp-2014'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_calendar_circuit',
            'value' => $circuit,
            'compare' => '=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )    
));
```

But this is not what I'm trying to achieve, I need to show related reports.

---

This `reports_race_event` meta key contains the id number of the 'event', and the 'event' contains the meta key `event_calendar_circuit` which contains the circuit id.

My question is how do I do this for 'reports', when the only meta_key I have is `reports_race_event`

I need to list 'reports' which we're held at a specific `$circuit`

If any one can help me that would be great thanks.

---

**I've figured out how I can do this!**

But I still need help please, I can list all related reports like this...

```
$related_reports = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'reports',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'reports_race_event',
            'value' => $events_at_circuit,
            'compare' => not sure,
            'type' => not sure
        )
    )    
));
```

But I need to create an array of 'event' id numbers and store it in this `$events_at_circuit` variable.

Buy using this query first...

```
global $circuit;

$related_events = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => array('motogp-2013','motogp-2014'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_calendar_circuit',
            'value' => $circuit,
            'compare' => '=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )    
));
```

My question is now, how do I get the returned post id numbers from the $related_events query and store them as an array in `$events_at_circuit`

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got there...

Here is the answer, I had to store the array numbers for the events that where at that circuit, then queried by meta_key value using an array variable. Then comparing using wordpress meta IN comparison. See full code below...

```
$events_at_circuit = null;

$related_events = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => array('motogp-2013','motogp-2014'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_calendar_circuit',
            'value' => $circuit,
            'compare' => '=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )    
));

if( !empty( $related_events ) ){ foreach( $related_events as $related_event ) $events_at_circuit[] =  $related_event->ID; }

$related_reports = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'reports',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'reports_race_event',
            'value' => $events_at_circuit,
            'compare' => 'IN',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )    
));

if ( $related_reports->have_posts() ) :
```